# Passing variable from Controller to Model

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I've some problem about passing variable in CI.

Model

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
{
    $id = $this->det_survey_id($id);
    //$this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->SELECT('id_pertanyaan,isi_pertanyaan,judul_pilgan,id_survey')
            ->FROM('pertanyaan')
            ->JOIN('pilgan','pertanyaan.id_pilgan=pilgan.id_pilgan','inner')
            ->WHERE('id_survey',$id);
```

Controller

```
public function edit($id){
    $this->load->model('Survey_Model');
    $data=array(
        'select_option' => $this->Survey_Model->get_pilgan(),
        'id_survey'     => $this->Survey_Model->det_survey_id($id),
        'judul_survey'  => $this->Survey_Model->det_survey_judul(),
        );  
    $this->load->view('include/header.php');
    $this->load->view('tambah_pertanyaan',$data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer.php');
}
```

How to pass Variable from Controller `$id` to Model `$id = $this->det_survey_id($id);`

Comment: what do you mean by : $id to Model $id = $this->det_survey_id($id); ?

Comment: $id is parameter from Controller, how to passing to Model?

Comment: you should pass the $id as a argument in the controller's method . this way you can always have access to model's method that associated with that controller's method

Comment: please look my script in comment

Comment: Model's method should be public in case you want to use it in controller. Read about [method visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Answer (score 0):

My Model

```
    private function _get_datatables_query($id)
{
    //$id = 87;//$this->Survey_Model->det_survey_id(87);
    //$this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->SELECT('id_pertanyaan,isi_pertanyaan,judul_pilgan,id_survey')
            ->FROM('pertanyaan')
            ->JOIN('pilgan','pertanyaan.id_pilgan=pilgan.id_pilgan','inner')
            ->WHERE('id_survey',$id);
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}

function get_datatables($id)
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query($id);
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function count_filtered($id)
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query($id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

My Controller

```
 public function ajax_list($id)
    {
        $list = $this->pertanyaan->get_datatables($id);
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $survey) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $survey->isi_pertanyaan;
            $row[] = $survey->judul_pilgan;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$survey->id_pertanyaan."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$survey->id_pertanyaan."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->pertanyaan->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->pertanyaan->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

My View

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

            //datatables
            table_pertanyaan = $('#table_pertanyaan').DataTable({ 

                "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
                "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
                "order": [], //Initial no order.

                // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "<?php echo site_url('pertanyaan/ajax_list/')?>/" + id,
                    "type": "POST"
                },

                //Set column definition initialisation properties.
                "columnDefs": [
                { 
                    "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
                ],
```

Parm controller `public function ajax_list($id)` error